# Declaring an extension method in Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

I come from a C# background and am trying to find an equivalent in implementing extension methods for types. I am using Angular 6, but I feel like this may be a typescript question as well.

I have declared a new file in my application:

```
// myExtensions.ts

import { TypeToExtend } from 'path_to_type';

declare module 'path_to_type' {
  interface TypeToExtend {
    newMethod(): string;
  }
}

TypeToExtend.prototype.newMethod = function(): string {
  return this.Whatever + ' Hello World';
};
```

And in one of my services I consume it as following:

```
typeToExtendObject.newMethod();
```

newMethod() shows up just fine in the VS Code intellisense, however when I actually run the application I see the error:

> "typeToExtendObject.newMethod() is not a function"

Do I have to add this to my modules somehow? Am I not exporting this extensions module correctly?

Comment: Do you import the extension module where you use the extension ?

Comment: Yes by a type I mean a model with properties and functions, I am trying to define a new function on an existing model.

@Titian, where would I import the module? In the angular module that my service lives in? What would I put in the imports array since I am not exporting a module in my extensions typescript file?

Comment: Somthing like `import { TypeToExtend } from 'path_to_type'; import './myExtensions';`

Comment: This will work for `TypeToExtend` instances, but not mocks thereof.

Comment: Adding import './myExtensions' into my angular service did not work btw

Comment: (Accidentally pressed Enter.)  You may be better off using a plain ol' function.  Is the dot notation buying you anything special?

Comment: At this point I'm thinking the same...

Answer (score 1):

It gets messy, mainly because most of your type information goes away after compilation.  You *could* write a function that takes an object (instance), and imbues that object with the method:

```
interface NewMethodable {
    newMethod(): string;
}
addExtension<T>(obj: T): T & NewMethodable {
    obj.newMethod = function ...;  // edited from original answer
    return <T & NewMethodable>obj;
}
```

This is very much off the cuff, so there are probably bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `export class` then your class will be visible, and `import` it  where you want to use it. even the class could be `static` to not use a instance.

```
export class User {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  car: Car;

  newFunction(){
    //TODO
  }

}
```

Comment: Actually, it looks like OP is trying to add a method to an _existing_ class (that someone else wrote).

Comment: Have to try (maybe @Lexi can comment), but does typescript/angular support inheritance where in your example User can be inherited from my TypeToExtend?

export class User: TypeToExtend { ..

Then I would be able to define my extension method and still reference 'this' to reference the TypeToExtend properties

Comment: Yes, you _can_ use the `extends` keyword to subclass something; but then it's no longer an _extension_ method (which is a dotNET concept).